# Quarkus Two-Way TLS: Backend does not accept the certificate

Tags: java, ssl, quarkus, mtls

I am trying to implement mTLS by my own regarding to the tutorial from https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-mutual-tls/.

This is how I have generated `server-keystore`, `client-keystore` and `server-trustore`

```
keytool -genkeypair \
        -storepass password \
        -keyalg RSA \
        -keysize 2048 \
        -dname "CN=example-server" \
        -alias server \
        -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" \
        -keystore ./server-keystore.jks

keytool -genkeypair \
        -storepass password \
        -keyalg RSA \
        -keysize 2048 \
        -dname "CN=example-client" \
        -alias client \
        -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" \
        -keystore ./client-keystore.jks


cp ./client-keystore.jks ./server-truststore.jks

keytool -exportcert \
        -alias client \
        -storepass password \
        -keystore ./server-truststore.jks \
        -rfc \
        -file client.pem
```

as you can see the `server-truststore` is a copy of `client-keystore`. Afterwards, I have exported the certificate from server-truststore and named it as `client.pem`.

Doing the request to the backend via curl `curl --cert client.crt https://localhost:8443/hello` it complains:

```
curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate, LibreSSL error error:02FFF002:system library:func(4095):No such file or directory, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
```

I assume that the private key is missing in the certificate `client.crt`. Regarding to [Use and utility of .p12 certificate/file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604668/use-and-utility-of-p12-certificate-file) I thing I need to generate `client.p12` file that also contains the private key.

I also tried via Postman with the following certificate configuration:
[image]

Unfortunately, I have got a bad response:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is that I would like to generate client certificates and provide it to customers, so that they can do the request to the backend server.

The code is hosted on https://github.com/softshipper/playwithmtls.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710543/175554 may help